# conditional probability: climbing ladders up or down with 1/2 chance

Tags: probability

a robot can climb up the ladder or climb down. There are 3 bars of the ladder. Each time robot climb it, there is 1/2 chance to go up or down (except he is at the first bar of the stairs).

**Question: what's the chance for the robot to successfully reach the 3rd bar of the ladder?**

(it's surely not just 1/2 * 1/2 * 1/2, cuz there is chance he can climb down during the process, so that's really bugging me... )

Comment: What do you know?

Comment: Are you assuming that if he reaches level 0, he stops?

Comment: 1. just assuming he is on the ground and want to climb up to reach the third level. 
2. If he reaches level 1 ( for me, I call the ground level 1, not 0 ), he has to climb up again, until he reaches level 3, then stops

Comment: Yes but if he keeps moving up and down all day, of course he will eventually reach the third floor.  Are there floors beneath ground level?  I've given an answer assuming he terminates his journey if he ever reaches the ground floor.

Comment: Ah, the clue is in the post title but not mentioned in the post itself.  You say he can only move 3 times?

Comment: sorry about that, he can move infinite times, just until he reaches level 3, he stops. and there are only 3 levels in this world. level 1 -> 2 -> 3.

Comment: the title is wrong, i gotta change it >"<

Comment: I should rephrase it, there isn't "level", I should just call it "bars", there are 3 bars on the ladder, robot climbing up and down.

Comment: ok, rephrase it done. sorry about my poor English Q_Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in the model you have in mind, the robot starts at bar 1, goes to bar 2, flips an even coin to decide if it goes back to bar 1 (heads) or to bar 3 (tails), stops if it is at bar 3, and starts all over again if it is back at bar 1.

Thus the robot goes to bar 3 at the first tails in a sequence of heads and tails. The event that the $n$ first draws are heads has probability $\frac1{2^n}$ and $\frac1{2^n}\to0$ hence sooner or later a tails occurs, almost surely. Thus, the probability to reach bar 3 is $1$.

**Edit:** This also indicates that the probability the robot reaches bar 3 at its $(2n)$th move or before is the probability that at least one tails occurs during $n$ draws, that is, $1-\frac1{2^n}$.

Comment: interesting! how dumb I am, never thought about this, yes, if the robot can try infinite times, he will reach the 3rd bars! BUT, it raises another question to me, if the robot can only climb up for the given amount of times, can I count the probability he reaches the 3rd bar?

Comment: Yes you can (see Edit).

Comment: really thankful to your answer. I tried to digest it but couldn't understand why is at least only "one tails", why not 2 tails, cuz from bar 1 to bar 2, one tails, bar 2 to bar 3, another tails, so totally will be 2 tails? Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing reaching the $0^{th}$ floor means the robot stops, let $P(1)$ and $P(2)$ be the chance the robot reaches the third floor from starting at the first and second floor respectively.  Then

$$P(1) = \frac{1}{2} P(2)$$
$$P(2) = \frac{1}{2} P(1) + \frac{1}{2}$$

Use these to solve for $P(1)$

Edit:  I just noticed you said he gets $3$ moves.  Then yes, the chances would simply be $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3$ since he needs to move up 3 times to reach level $3$ from level $0$.

Comment: cool! thanks, but if he won't stop at 0th floor (1st floor), he has to keep climbing up until he gets to 3rd level?

Comment: If there is no restriction placed on when he terminates his journey or unless there's an infinite number of floors below level $3$, the chances of him eventually reaching level $3$ will be $1$.

Comment: much appreciated your kindly discussion with me! really like to vote up, but no reputation I've got >"<

Answer (score 0):

The robot will reach the top of the ladder with probability $1$.

Comment: great answer! really like to vote up, but no reputation I've got >"<